# How to get all associated information on relationship tables?

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

I have some related tables and for the main this is the Model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Information extends AppModel {
public $useTable = 'informations';
public $displayField = 'name';
public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'The field name can not be empty',
        ),
    ),
    'lastname' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'The field lastname can not be empty',
        ),
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'message' => 'The email address is not correct',
        ),
    ),
);

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Country' => array(
        'className' => 'Country',
        'foreignKey' => 'countries_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

public $hasMany = array(
        'Education' => array(
                'className' => 'Education',
                'foreignKey' => 'informations_id',
                'dependent' => true
        ),
        'Experience' => array(
                'className' => 'Experience',
                'foreignKey' => 'informations_id',
                'dependent' => true
        ),
        'Attachment' => array(
                'className' => 'Attachment',
                'foreignKey' => 'informations_id',
                'dependent' => true
        )
);
```

}

I need to get all the data related to a ID but when I try to get the data using this code:

```
  public function view($id = null) {
    $this->Information->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Information->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid information'));
    }
    $this->set('information', $this->Information->read(null, $id));
}
```

The information from tables Education, Experience and Attachment is not showed only this info is get:

```
Array
(
   [id] => 9
   [name] => Reynier
   [lastname] => Perez Mira
   [email] => reynierpm@gmail.com
   [mobile_phone] => 04241805609
   [home_phone] => 02735555899
   [address] => asdas
   [picture] => skills.png
   [other_information] => asdasdasd
   [recruitment_status] => Call for Interview
   [countries_id] => 9
)
```

Why? I miss something?

Comment: Try setting $this->Information->recursive = 1; on the line before the read.  You could/should also look into the "Containable" behavior in the CakePHP book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your function to set the recursive on Information:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $this->Information->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Information->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid information'));
    }
    $this->Information->recursive = 1;
    $this->set('information', $this->Information->read(null, $id));
}
```

Then just make sure all of your relationships in your Information model are setup to point to the other models you want to include.